# String data neo4j cypher query by passing DESC or ASC as a parameter

Tags: cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have a neo4j cypher query like below:

```
@Query("START ... RETURN createDate ORDER BY createDate {2} SKIP {0} LIMIT {1}")
Iterable<SomeGraphObject> findSomeGraphObjects(int start, int offset, String sortBy);
```

Is it possible to pass **DESC** or **ASC** as a parameter to query string ?. I am trying to achieve this using `sortBy` parameter.

**Edit**

My complete query:

```
@Query("START user=node({0}) MATCH user-[l:LIKE]->blog WHERE blog.status = 0 RETURN blog ORDER BY l.likeDate {3} SKIP {1} LIMIT {2}")
Iterable<BlogLikesData> findBlogLikesData(UserGraph userGraph, int start, int offset, String sortBy);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, you are looking for pagination with sorting of data.
In spring data neo4j, you can achieve pagination simply by using `PageRequest`.

```
@Query("START n... RETURN createDate order by n.createdDate DESC") // or ASC
Iterable<SomeGraphObject> findSomeGraphObjects(String someparameter, Pageable pageable);
```

you may call `findSomeGraphObjects` as:

```
obj.findSomeGraphObjects("XYZ",new PageRequest(int start, int pageSize));
```

**Update**
I am not sure, but I guess reserved keyword cannot be given as an argument, you need to explicitly mention it into your query.

Comment: Sorry maybe my question is not very clear, i don't want to hardcode "DESC" in my query string, so i manage to pass sortBy as a parameter which is {2} in my question.

Comment: Ah.. ok, I am not sure because reserved keyword cannot be passed as an argument I guess. did you tried ur code? what was the outcome ?

Comment: Hi Aman, Thanks for your help, here is outcome: "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Error executing statement START...", i think you are right, it's not possible to do it.

Comment: Wait, can you provide me complete cypher query written under @Query block ?

Comment: Hi Aman, i updated my question to include complete cypher query string, thanks for your time.

Comment: Sorry, dont have enough idea, but I would like to suggest you, for block {0} and {3} mention its value explicitly into the query itself and re run you program to check output. for block {0} i.e. inside node `className="youPackage.yourClassName"`